Is it possible to disable or rewrite _anonymous() function in yocto bb file
As title:
Is it possible to disable or rewrite _anonymous() function in yocto bb file by a bbappend file.
python __anonymous() {
    ................
    ................
}


Try:
__anonymous[noexec] = "1"

or:
python __anonymous() {
    :
}

